# Ubuntu freeze on boot purple screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, freeze, 19.04

After a day of restarting my computer i finally given up. 
I had Ubuntu 18.10 installed and worked perfectly and then i got the upgrade prompt and upgraded to 19.04. The upgrade crashed and after that the system was still booting except 80% of the time. Most of the boots resulted in a purple screen and that is all. I tried everything on the web and nothing seams to work. It is very very random. Couldn't find a way to see where it hangs. The frozen boots fo not appear in the journal.
If i try to boot the recovery both messages appear so loads the kernel and the other thing and then it hangs. 
I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10 (with updates) and had the same problem.
I did the upgrade (which this time worked) to 19.04 and same problem.
Now I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 without any updates and i got it working 4/4 boots.
I did the updates 400ish mb of updates and then started doing the same thing with the purple screen.
I reinstalled the 18.04.2 and didn't do the updates.

I have no other options than to hope.. I have a Zenbook UX433FA and dualboot with Windows. I guess it is one of the packages that gets updated on 18.04.2 but i don't know which one.

Thank you.

edit: before the 18.10 reinstall i did a fresh reinstall of 19.04

Answer (score 0):

If you already reinstalled Ubuntu a few times, then I guess you don't need to upgrade it. You should make a fresh 19.04 installation instead, which is safer than an upgrade.

After fresh installation you should also change `/etc/default/grub` options, to see more messages and errors on your script while booting the system.

Please edit `/etc/default/grub` and remove `quiet splash` flags from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

```
sudo editor /etc/default/grub
```

Then repleace:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

and update grub with:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Then when you're stuck you can take a picture of your screen with a smartphone, upload it to i.e. imgur.com and share it in your question, if it shows any errors.

Another thing you may want to try is to use `nomodeset` option for safe graphics option.

- [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

However as I said it's better to remove `quiet splash` options, so you can see logs during boot, that may help resolving the problem.

Comment: I forgot to say the first reinstall was a 19.04 and then the 18.10. i tried removing the quiet splash and add nomodeset i tried removing load_video and everything i could find on the web but still the same config didn't work every time. it is random. i don't have nvidia just the integrated graphics. if i add acpi=off it stops after "freeing kernel memory" but i think that it stops there because of acpi=off.  is there a difference between update-grub and update-grub2 ?

Comment: Most likely update-grub2 is a symlink to update-grub. It's a simple bash script. You can check if this is a symlink with `ls -la /usr/sbin/update-grub /usr/sbin/update-grub2` In such case: no, there is no diffrence.

Comment: i updated the kernels to 4.19.43 with ukuu and until now is still working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues. On way to start the machine is:

- login via ssh from an other machine `ssh <user@machine_name or IP>`
- restart gdm `sudo service gdm restart`

There might be options to add this to a boot script. I do not recommend this since it seems to happen to more people which asks for a general fix..

Answer (score 0):

> Now I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 without any updates and i got it
>   working 4/4 boots. I did the updates 400ish mb of updates and then
>   started doing the same thing with the purple screen. I reinstalled the
>   18.04.2 and didn't do the updates.

This is exactly what's happening to me on fresh installs of 18.04.2. Had this issue start after updates last Friday. Posted in detail on it here: [Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete video about this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbxrSaclKRc

Summary of the fix:

1. add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub
2. update-grub

More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620

What actually is a proper fix, is to update your firmware. In the last version this is no longer an issue.