# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on purple screen Asus Zenbook UX433FA

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I recently got an Asus Zenbook UX433FA dh, 16 Gb of ram, 8Th generation Intel Core i7-8565u quad Core Processor (8M Cache, up to 4.1 GHz) graphic card: UHD Graphics 620.
I successfully installed ubuntu 18.04 using a usb bootdrive. The issue arise after updating ubuntu through the software update center. I looked for any additional drivers on the software update app and it did not find any. 
Now upon booting I get stuck on a purple screen.
Here is what I have try so far:

- access boot option by pressing e and run nomodeset quiet splash without ro -> sometimes I can login but the resolution is very low and cannot be changed along with the brightness that is high and cannot be changed sometimes I get stuck at the purple screen.
- tried using nomoedeset only, quiet splash only -> boot to the purple screen
- tried beignet-opencl, no difference (or don't know because inconsistent)
- tried xserver-xorg-video-intel mesa-utils (dependency problem with xserver-xorg-core) -> worse now only black screen never login

I looked every where online tried to fix it with a friend familiar with linux nothing seems to worked so far!

**Edit**
It looks like this may be an issue with intel-microcode see this thread with the same question that is more active: [Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates)

Comment: For others having the same issue, let me also confirm that this is an issue (mainly) affecting users of Ubuntu on recent Asus models with 8th-gen Intel processors. We solved the issue by using the accepted solution on the linked thread - adding  dis_ucode_ldr   to the GRUB boot options to disable intel microcode.

Comment: This solved it all. I looked for an answer for so long... This guy should get an award. [README with a lot of fixes regarding Ubuntu and Zenbooks](https://github.com/ShangChunLin/zenbook-issuse-with-ubuntu18.04).

Comment: @MindS1 this solutions finally worked for me, nothing related with nvide or using nouveau modeset worked for me, my asus is a vivobook S15 recent, but what is the problem? How come thenew  Asus models with 8th-gen Intel processors have this problem and nobody fix it?