# Ubuntu 18.04.4 won't boot after Kernel update, stuck at loading initial ramdisk

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, kernel

I just installed new kernel using this command on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 computer:

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Installation was successful. However, after this update, I cannot boot when I select newest Kernel on GRUB. It stucks on purple screen where "Loading initial ramdisk..." is read.

I can boot into the old version, but now it takes a little longer to boot and prints [these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCKko.jpg), I am not sure if they mean something.

And there is something strange. When I boot into Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, I see no lines printed, just the purple screen. But when I select advanced settings and boot the first entry which is the newest kernel I see the lines indicating kernel version and saying "Loading initial ramdisk..." It is strange because when I boot Ubuntu, it should boot the first entry as well. So why doesn't it print the lines then?

System Info:
Dell Inspiron 5567 with i7 7500U
Upgraded from Kernel 4.15.0.91

The solution proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1146150/1020320) did not solve my problem.

EDIT: A new update (5.3.0-45) came up and I installed it today and the problem remains for both this entry in GRUB and the previous one (5.3.0-42). Oldest one (4.15.0.91) can be booted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Dell Inspiron 17 5767 which was exhibiting the same issue(s). A clean Ubuntu 18.04.4 install works fine. But as soon as I updated packages, when this jumped to kernel 5.3.0.28-generic, my laptop stopped booting, and froze at "loading initial ramdisk". Using dis_ucode_ldr did not help. Updating the Dell BIOS did not help. When adding debug options to the kernel command line, nothing was displayed.

This link solved the problem for me: [Ubuntu 20.04 black screen after installing, no booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229910/ubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-installing-no-booting)
"The problem is with UEFI. To fix it you can turn off PPT in the UEFI/BIOS options and enable Legacy Boot."

When I disabled PPT and enabled Legacy Boot, my Dell laptop recovered and can now boot successfully. Hopefully this might help.

Answer (score 0):

i'm a new ubuntu user, i just want to share a link for you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553518/stuck-at-loading-initial-ramdisk-after-attempt-to-update-the-kernel

hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In safe-mode or command line, edit /etc/default/grub and replace in the existing configuration line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

with

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr"

the issue is either caused by restarting in a different display configuration that it was prior. Either previously having connected a display and starting without it, or not having and starting with it. It happens when having set up UEFI startup mode, and might be fixed by BIOS update.

The usual way of fixing ramdisk issue here apt update && apt upgrade here did not help, or helped in connection with the mentioned solution.