# Boot Freezes and "Loading initial Ramdisk"

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 19 to Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday and then on restart my Laptop (Alienware 17r4, Nvidea GTX1070) freezes at "Loading initial Ramdisk"

I googled a lot and applied couple of workarounds but it didn't help:

> - Adding nomodeset -  Didn't help.
> - Updated my Bios Firmware from Dell - Didn't help.
> - Updating grub2 - Didn't help.

The weird thing is that when I enable Secure Boot from Bios, it lets me Boot one time and then it does not let me boot  upon restart. I have disable Secure boot again, then when I boot, I boot up to Login screen of Ubuntu but it does not let me pass through even after entering the correct password and then when I enable secure boot it lets me boot Normally (very slow).

I tried to follow: [Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot even in recovery mode (stuck on loading initial ram disk) on ASUS UX433FA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145856/ubuntu-18-04-fails-to-boot-even-in-recovery-mode-stuck-on-loading-initial-ram-d)
but I don't think the mentioned Intel drivers are available for Ubuntu 20.04:

NB: *I am using Nvidea Proprietary drivers (nvidea-driver-440).*

Comment: The fix for me was i didn't have enough CPU cores. I up'd it from 1 to 4 booted straight away

Answer (score 5):

In safe-mode or command line, edit `/etc/default/grub` and replace in the existing configuration line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

with

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr"`

the issue is either caused by restarting in a different display configuration that it was prior. Either previously having connected a display and starting without it, or not having and starting with it. It happens when having set up UEFI startup mode, and might be fixed by BIOS update.

The usual way of fixing ramdisk issue here `apt update && apt upgrade` here did not help, or helped in connection with the mentioned solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had issue with microcode on 19.10 (but it seems resolved recently).

But after update to 20.04 my laptop was freezing when try to start w/o charger plugged. Adding `dis_ucode_ldr` to grub helped in my case:

See: https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/td-p/7449042/page/3

UPD. BIOS update also helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

There is actual intel driver available for TFF?

See:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode

You can also check for new version in terminal

```
apt-cache show intel-microcode | grep Version
```

Wich shows the latest "stable" one usually.

Comment: What exactly is "TFF?"

Answer (score 0):

bios update to 302 version helped me with asus ux305u (intel graphics).

no more freeze at boot for both ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04.5