# Remove "$vt_handoff" from GRUB menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, password-recovery

Hey I am very unexperienced so I hope this is not a question that I could have been answering myself by further research.

I forgot the password to my own machine and found out that there's a workaround by entering the Grub-menu and adding `init=/bin/bash` at the end of the "linux-line", and then booting with <kbd>F10</kbd>. I have the problem, that my machine freezes after that showing `Loading initial ramdisk`.

I found that this is a common problem ([Boot Freezes and "Loading initial Ramdisk"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240152/boot-freezes-and-loading-initial-ramdisk)) but cannot fix it by replacing `quiet splash` with `dis_ucode_ldr` (as the linked thread suggests). I now removed the `$vt_handoff` from the line and now my system boots, yet I am somehow suspicious that I am destroying something because I have zero experience.

Can I cause any harm by removing the `$vt_handoff` section from the GRUB menu, when booting?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no harm. `$vt_handoff` just makes the boot look a bit nicer.
[A bit more details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vt.handoff) are at help.ubuntu.com.