# BUG Black Screen At Boot Time

Tags: boot, kernel

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, with Linux 4.15.0-1087-oem.

Notebook model: DELL LATITUDE 7400. No discrete video card.

The problem appeared suddenly and recently, probably after a system update. First, the loader window appears, I press Enter on the Ubuntu item - the download does not go, but sometimes it loaded without problems. I did all the manipulations with the parameters: neither `nomodeset` nor others help. Now it doesn't start at all. All loader parameters are in their original state.

During these "black screens" the notebook starts to get very warm.

Edited the loader configuration file `/etc/default/grub`:

```
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

Updated the loader. Checking information about the current kernel (kernel release):

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-1080-oem
```

So now 4.15.0-1080-oem is loaded by default.
But that's half the case. There is some serious problem with the latest boot-loaders (4.15.0-1087-oem & 4.15.0-1081-oem) - an obvious bug, there are fresh posts about it in the web... And how to solve this problem?

Maybe you just need to wait for the error to be fixed, and don't update the system until then?

Comment: you can try to use other kernel in Advanced Options during the boot time, see if you have the issue. If yes then the problem is in the kernel, and maybe you can install other kernel which solves the issue

Comment: Exactly. And I did it. What's next? Wait for bug-fixing?

Comment: so you have only this two kernels 4.15.0-1087-oem & 4.15.0-1081-oem and both of them have the same issue ? You can try to install other kernel, but be aware if something goes wrong or not properly installed you need to install from scratch if you dont have a backup..

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS uses Kernel 5.3 and I'm wondering why you have Kernel 4.15 in your system installed ? Are you using the laptop daily and did not update the system ?

Comment: I am new to Linux. The application manager reports that the software is up to date. Kernel releases 4.15.0-1087-oem & 4.15.0-1081-oem don't work (have the same issue), so I use 4.15.0-1080-oem.

Comment: Atleast get a dmesg log or something. We need more information!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Notebook model: DELL LATITUDE 7400
The black screen was (violet'ish color of grub)

I can boot either with linux 4.15.0-1087-oem or 4.15.0-1081-oem but only when I boot up from the power button.

But hangs if I power up from plugin AC or USB-C Dock cable or if I use software reboot.

So I uncheck in the BIOS the options "Wake on Dell USB-C Dock" and "Wake on AC" in "Power Management" section. And try not to use reboot with software command but use the power button.

I thinks the issue is with Grub 2.02.
I modified /etc/default/grub with the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
...
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

So now when I reboot(with software command) it display indefinitely "loading kernel 4.15.0-1087-oem"

But I can boot when I power up my laptop using the power button (with plugin AC or USB-C Dock cable) and selecting manually kernel 4.15.0-1087-oem in grub menu.

it seems the auto selection of kernel in grub 2.02 doesn't work well on dell latitude 7400 laptops!

Comment: I still have the issue with kernel 4.15.0-1091-oem.

Comment: Latitude 7400:
The same problem with kernel ...1091... Works only with ...1080...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work even without plugin AC cable or by restarting ubuntu with this post:

[Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot even in recovery mode (stuck on loading initial ram disk) on ASUS UX433FA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145856/ubuntu-18-04-fails-to-boot-even-in-recovery-mode-stuck-on-loading-initial-ram-d)

You need to add `dis_ucode_ldr` to in `/etc/default/grub`

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash dis_ucode_ldr"
```

Then :

```
sudo update-grub
```

And get the specific version of intel-microcode:

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

Since this bug didn't showed up the fresh install of my laptop I guess the intel-microcode update did introduce it!