# How to roll back intel microcode update on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates, microcode

Just two days ago (Jun 18, 2019), I was prompted to allow a routine Ubuntu update. After update finished and reboot, I'm no longer able to boot into Ubuntu. Specifically, I was taken to the Grub screen, select 'ubuntu', then face a purple screen, nothing happens afterward.

There's this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates), addressing I think the same issue. My question is :

Is it possible to roll back the Intel microcode change without doing what is suggested there,

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

Reason this is not possible is, in terminal mode, I have no access to internet.

Comment: Have you looked in /var/cache/apt/archives/ to see if what you want to return to isn't already on your system (though if you're regular in cleaning/autoremove it may not be) as this would allow `dpkg`..

Comment: @guiverc Would microcode updates be in there?  What would the file look like (name)? Will definitely look into, thks for suggesting this location.

Comment: I assume so, however my system was autoclean/autoremove in the last 15 hours so I don't see any microcode in mine (loads of other files as I'm running 19.10), but it'll look like a file found here http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/intel-microcode/  You could always download the version you want from this site using your existing device, transfer via sneaker-net (*ie. tape/floppy/thumb-drive*) and `dpkg -i` install that.  (apt-get will use `dpkg` to do actual install once it's got everything..  ie. what your post talked of really as a fix just by-passing `apt-get`

Answer (score 2):

You need any System with internet access. Direkt download link [intel-microcode_3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb 64-bit](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/360608605/intel-microcode_3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb)

or for 32-bit [intel-microcode_3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1_i386.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/360608608/intel-microcode_3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1_i386.deb)

Save the file to an usb-stick. boot your bionic in recovery-mode. Make sure /-partition in mount rw. `mount -o remount,rw /` mount the usb-stick and install the package directly with dpkg