# Ubuntu 18.04.3 freezing on boot

Tags: boot

I got new Dell Vostro 3480 laptop. It had Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled. I updated to 18.04.3. With 18.04.3, after the BIOS, the screen freezes and it does not boot. The login works sometimes, but does not work other times.

What could be wrong? I have built-in intel graphics. I tried following things, 
1. Setting WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file
2. Setting lightdm as display manager
3. Disabling splash screen on boot-up, so I can see boot console messages. But there are no console messages. The screen freezes before console messages are displayed.

I have now reverted back to 18.04 and I don't experience any problem with 18.04.

What could be the issue with 18.04.3, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is problem due to intel microcode issue. There are two solutions to this problem,

1. add a instruction dis_ucode_ldr in your grub file,
2. Update the BIOS. The updated BIOS seems to be working for my Dell Vostro.

You can see more details in a comprehensive forum post [Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates)