# Latest ubuntu 18.04.4 (linux 4.15.0-1073-oem) stuck at purple screen

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, dell, bios

I have a Dell Precision 3530 running stock ubuntu 18.04 LTS (I got it with this installed).
After recent update my system won't boot using latest kernel available:

```
linux 4.15.0-1073-oem
```

But instead boots fine if selecting from grub

```
linux 4.15.0-1069-oem
```

or

```
linux 4.15.0-1021-oem
```

Has anyone else experienced this?
I tried to update manually after seeing this but it didn't solve, moreover I noticed this while doing `sudo apt-get update`:

> Err:25 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell Release.gpg
>     The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG F9FDA6BED73CDC22 Canonical Archive Automatic Signing Key

**EDIT 1**
I noticed that even with other kernel version it often doesn't boot. I don't know why sometimes it does, but following this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates/1145959) I am able to boot adding `dis_ucode_ldr` to GRUB launch command each time I want to boot.
I guess next step is to wait for a dell update.

**EDIT 2**
Trying to use a more recent kernel (Kernel 5.3) as suggested below again seems to fix the problem, but it really does not. After a couple of reboots, still stuck at purple screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS moved to kernel 5.3. You could try to use it by

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

*xorg* also will be upgraded.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

History of 18.04 kernels:

- Ubuntu 18.04 - 4.15
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 - 4.18
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 - 5.0
- Ubuntu 18.04.4 - 5.3

Comment: thanks, this seems to solve. But why he new kernel wasn't included in the updates I installed?

Comment: Actually it is still giving the same problems as before and the fix is still the one I linked. The problem might not be the kernel then.

Comment: @a_bet could you please test your hardware: Memtest86+ (included in boot menu GRUB) for RAM, Victoria for HDD/SSD? Also check HDD/SSD free space.

Comment: Hi @Serhii thank for the comment. I'm on UEFI so I don't see memtest86 in grub. I found this (https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) do you think it's a trustable source? I ran large tests using the diagnostic tools in my firmware from Dell (access from UEFI) and everything seems to be ok on HW side. SSD is only half full