# Ubuntu 18.04.4 Lts unable to Boot after Update stuck on purple screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, updates, dell

Everything was working fine previous day when i turn on my laptop I'm stuck on restart loop unable to boot after GNU GRUB screen. My Ubuntu did updated previous day and i selected Restart later option

When i select Advance Option for Ubuntu i get 4 options as seen in image below

[Image][1]

Selecting both recover mode options i get

```
Loading Linux 5.3.0-42-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

then black screen then my system restart

and selecting other options i get black screen then my system restart

**I have Tried this but don't work for me**

Some posts suggested this solution
On GRUB menu Press 'e' and changing quiet splash nomodeset 
Pressed Ctrl + X

still get black screen and computer restart

I have Ubuntu IOS on usb but the installing Ubuntu i don't get reinstalling Ubuntu while keeping my data

Recovered my data but fresh installation also have same problem after Update

My system:
Dell inspiron i3 15 3567
Intel HD 520 integrated

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:**

i tried to apply these solutions but none works for me
[Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates)

After trying to fix my problem i know my Ubuntu Break (hang to purple screen) after these updated is installed and computer is restarted as shown in image below

[Ubuntu update list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXTsS.png)

I really cant do any more debugging because i need my laptop for work

```
System info : 
     Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
     VGA compatible controller
     product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
     vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, to salvage your data, create [system rescue](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/)CD and cope your home directory to another media. Or use `fsarchiver` to backup the entire partition then you can try anything.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka but i can't go pass the GNU GRUB screen system keep restarting

Comment: From the GRUB Additional Options menu, try and boot the -40 kernel. Does that fully boot? Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: System rescue CD/USB is another way to boot your computer, it's independent. Enter BIOS and select external device, but you need another computer to create it.

Comment: @heynnema I recovered my data using USB boot and did the fresh Ubuntu installation then after update same problem this time i get purple Screen instead of black screen

Comment: @heynnema i guess i use Ubuntu with disable update, Other people have same issue like this  
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates

Comment: The key would have been to see if the prior -40 kernel still booted, as per my comment from yesterday. We would have learned a lot from that. Oh well.

Comment: @heynnema sorry but i don't know what --40 kernel is im noob at Linux

Comment: GRUB menu, Additional Options, and you'd have seen all of the older kernels that you could have tried to boot from. Look closely at the image in your question. The -40 refers to that kernel. Had you tried it, and had it booted, then the fix for the -42 kernel might have been real easy.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell Inspiron 17 5767 which was exhibiting the same issue(s). A clean Ubuntu 18.04.4 install works fine. But as soon as I updated packages, when this jumped to kernel 5.3.0.28-generic, my laptop stopped booting, and froze at "loading initial ramdisk". Using dis_ucode_ldr did not help. Updating the Dell BIOS did not help. When adding debug options to the kernel command line, nothing was displayed.

This link solved the problem for me: [Ubuntu 20.04 black screen after installing, no booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229910/ubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-installing-no-booting)
"The problem is with UEFI. To fix it you can turn off PPT in the UEFI/BIOS options and enable Legacy Boot."

When I disabled PPT and enabled Legacy Boot, my Dell laptop recovered and can now boot successfully. Hopefully this might help.