# Ubuntu 20.04 black screen after installing, no booting

Tags: boot, 20.04

I´ve just installed 20.04 on my laptop, replacing 19.10.

The USB installer process worked perfectly, but after rebooting, I´m getting a black screen right after the grub, with no text, and selecting recovery mode gets stuck on "loading initial ramdisk".

I have tried editing the boot parameters, removing quiet splash, and changing gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode for gfxmode text, to be able to see some kind of info at boot, but the black screen still persists.

Any suggestion?

Machine:
DELL Inspiron 15 5567
AMD Radeon R7 M445 Graphics
Intel i7 Processor

Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 + Windows 10 (it was working fine with 19.10)

Bios:
Uefi, security OFF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: For reference, I also got this after upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04. There should have been a warning label or something for this.....

Comment: I've found that if I open a console (ctrl-alt-f2) and then return to tty1 (ctrl-alt-f1) the boot completes!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem. My computer is a Dell Inspiron 15.

The problem is with UEFI. To fix it you can turn off PPT in the UEFI/BIOS options and enable Legacy Boot.

Comment: Hey Victor, thank you!

It was the PPT option indeed, turning it off solves the problem.

Ubuntu can boot correctly now, it's a bit strange that 19.10 had no problem booting up, even with PPT turned on.

Comment: I have the same issue and I know that Ubuntu supports TPM (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) so in theory it should work as it did previously.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but I don't find any settings for PPT in BIOS. Can you please share where is located in Dell Inspiron 15 3521?

Comment: @DonTropo same pc and same probem here, can you say to us where to find that option?

Comment: You can find the "PPT Security" option  in the BIOS under the Security tab, you have to uncheck "PPT On". I did not have to enable the Legacy Boot in order to boot 20.04 correctly.

Comment: Note, I believe the above answer and comments seem to be talking about PTT Security (Platform Trust Technology), not PPT. (Do let me know if I'm wrong; PPT isn't googleable on this topic since its a file format...)

Comment: Not working - there is no PTT option in Dell XPS 8930 Desktop.

Comment: On brand new Latitude 5400, the PTT option is replaced by TPM (see https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr-fr/how12395/how-to-troubleshoot-and-resolve-common-issues-with-tpm-and-bitlocker?lang=en). But this change nothing, and the "Legacy Boot Mode" is no longer present. See the answser of @Amias (https://askubuntu.com/a/1250303/706066) for the right solution.

Answer (score 11):

I too found the same thing on my Inspiron 5567. I had PPT on also, but could still boot any Ubuntu version before 20.04 as well. I'm wondering what's causing this.

However, **I did not have to turn Legacy boot on**. Just turning PPT off worked just fine.

For those who are new to the BIOS, press `F2` when you see the Dell logo, go to `Security` -> `PTT Security` and uncheck `PTT On`. Click `Apply` (I would recommend choosing `Save as Custom User Settings`), then `OK`, then `Exit`.

Comment: If this question had a bounty I'd award it to you. How did you figure that out? You have my utmost respect.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs you can start a bounty on the question with "Reward existing answer". That's what I usually do :)

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem on a Dell Precision m3800. It seemed to have something to do with the boot splash screen.

I fixed it by disabling the splash. I did this by removing splash from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to apply the change.

Comment: i have not had problems with secure boot being on or off with ubuntu.

Comment: This solve the issue on a brand new Latitude 5400. Changing the TPM/PTT do nothing, and the Legacy Boot option is no longer present. So this is the right solution to apply.

Comment: I can't thank you enough Amias. I used your solution and it fixed my (very frustrating) problem. I have read other solutions and tried few but they did not work for me. Some solutions blame the AMD graphic card but I don't even have an AMD card. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Maybe your solution is connected with this of mine and related to UEFI, and can be applied in this full form, editing /etc/default/grub replacing 
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="dis_ucode_ldr"

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 I still see the blinking cursor instead of the login screen.

Comment: @FantomX1 thank you! Finally I booted the Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that I would get only a black screen when trying to boot 5.11.0.34, but I could boot 5.11.0.27 with no problem. I resolved it by stepping back from nvidia-driver-470 to nvidia-driver-450. You can find the GUI to make this change in Software & Updates | Additional Drivers.

Steve

Comment: Do you mean the kernel versions?