# I installed ubuntu from ISO on usb, and when it boots it only goes to grub menu

Tags: grub2, 20.04, iso, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 15 and it said "install successful, click restart" and when I restart it just opens the grub> menu. Why is that? How can I just load ubuntu and use my computer?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after upgrading a System76 desktop from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. It done this the day before on two laptops without having any issues. On-line suggestions included downloading and running a boot repair package and various other things, none of which worked.

What did work was NOT checking the box "install 3rd party software" in the install sequence. I eventually remembered having exactly this problem two years ago when I upgraded the same machine from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Once the install completed and it booted on its own properly, I went in and enabled these packages in the update manager manually.

I'll mention one other thing you might try if this doesn't work: take a look at this thread: [Ubuntu 20.04 black screen after installing, no booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229910/ubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-installing-no-booting)