# Black screen after grub selection

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I've tried installing six or seven different distros now, including Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, and they all suffer from the same thing: a black screen after boot. My monitor would actually go into its sleep mode.

I've tried all sorts of fixes found online, but the only one that would work is adding `nomodeset` to my grub config. Even so, `inxi -G` would result in `Device-1: Intel driver: N/A` and display configurations were limited. I'd prefer not to have to keep this setting in my grub config.

I'm doing this on a fresh install on a Dell OptiPlex Micro 7090 with an i7 10700 and its 630 iGPU.

Comment: You need newest kernel. And if you have not updated UEFI firmware, you need to do that .  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642535/xorg-detects-no-displays-with-an-intel-uhd-630 & Perhaps similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204648/install-ubuntu-on-dell-inspiron-14-7490

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tinkering, this is what I found:

- UEFI settings didn't matter. Some folks encouraged legacy boot, but that's not an option for my platform.
- [Others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229910/ubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-installing-no-booting) suggested disabling PPT in BIOS or removing the splash from grub settings. This didn't work for me.
- After reading a lot about Intel integrated GPUs not being recognized or not having the appropriate drivers loaded (which are part of the kernel), I tried using various flags for i915 support, but this didn't seem to be a great solution either.
- I tried upgrading my kernel. Apparently i915 support was fixed in the 5.11 branch. However, upgrading past 5.10 is apparently [broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1926938) on 20.04 and 20.10 unless you want to compile the kernel yourself or use a custom PPA (such as the one provided by [tuxinvader](https://hub.docker.com/r/tuxinvader/focal-mainline-builder)). Kernel versions 5.11 and beyond require libc6 >= 2.33 (if you're just pulling the .deb files for them) and updating that on 20.04 and 20.10 isn't really something I want to muck with for a brand new system that I hoped would just work.

What worked, in the end? **I just installed a fresh 21.04**. Worked out of the box because it ships with kernel version 5.11. No tinkering. No extra config. Just a solved problem.

So, if you're running into a similar issue and have the ability to start fresh or upgrade your distro, this was by far the most straightforward solution.

Extra tip: I needed to write the USB installer with GPT and not MBR due to the chipset/BIOS that this OptiPlex / i7 10700 ships with.