# Can't boot after upgrade to 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 14.04, uefi

I followed the procedure that Dell, Ubuntu team, and this posting suggest:
[Ubuntu 20.04 black screen after installing, no booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229910/ubuntu-20-04-black-screen-after-installing-no-booting/1250303#1250303?newreg=2628f627a3f041b89a45726891d6916c)
One problem, though.  Many of these call for changing a settings file - but I can't boot, and thus can't change the file.

Another online recommendation is to turn off 'PTT'and enable legacy boot.  But there are no options under the security tab (or anywhere else) that mention PTT.

This appears to be a very localized problem affecting Dell Inspiron 15 computers.

Comment: Update:  I did find PPI on the BIOS and turned it off.  It made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old answer I provided below.

Discovered the problem is driven by Ubuntu trying to use my external monitor.  What the flicker is is the normal "hiccup" that happens when you add a new monitor...it just keeps happening over and over.

The problem is well-known, and seems to involve the library used to drive graphics to the screen (including plain old text.

The problem is X-windows (or whatever it is called now)as the library driving the monitors.  The more up-to-date package for doing this is "Wayland", which Ubuntu is moving towards making the default.

In the meantime you can fix it by enabling Wayland.  To do that:

1. edit the file etc/ gdm3/custom.config (you'll need to use sudo to have enough privileges.  There is a line that mentions Wayland.  By default it is commented out.  It says "#WaylandEnable=False.
2. uncomment the line by removing "#'.
3. change the line to read "WaylandEnable=true".
4. Add the second monitor.

This answer was drawn from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1883534.

---

OLD ANSWER:
After a lot of time trying to sort this out, I have my computer stable enough as long as it doesn't turn off.
The tricks were:

1. rebooting Ubuntu 20 over-and-over, until it completes successfully (and doesn't deliver up error messages, a Grub CLI, or flashing screens).  No idea why this is needed.
2. turning off the auto-off feature.  Ubuntu becomes unstable if it goes into auto-off mode, leading to the flashing screen and frozen mouse, non-functioning commands, and loss of IO at times.  I simply turned off the auto-off mode that is there to save energy.
3. Downloaded new drivers (new to me) using CLI commands to allow (for example) the browser to render video.  The CLI command I used was "sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav".

Deep down I think the only thing that can cause this (errors both at boot *and* after the kernel is running) is the video card - though I can't definitively prove that.