# 18.04.2 Hangs during boot after update

Tags: boot, 18.04, updates

Two days ago, I accepted the updates for my Ubuntu 18.04.2 system yesterday and ever since it has booted to this screen and hung:
[image]
I tried a live boot CD and using boot-repair and got the same screen.
I have tried all of the options in the recovery console program and, the "resume" option allows my system to boot just fine, but nothing else helps and my system will not REBOOT after I have resumed from the recovery console.  ("Not reboot" means that it returns to the hang state at the screen above when I try to reboot.)  I also read through many of the similar sounding questions and responses here, but none were helpful.

So, I can use the recovery mode tool to resume into a working boot, but I would really prefer my system to ACTUALLY boot successfully.

Oh, FYI:  Nothing works except the power button when the screen above is displayed.  Neither left/right single/double mouse clicks nor any of the keys I have tried have had any effect.  It seems completely locked up.

[EDIT] Update:  I changed my grub settings from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

as suggested by the tread I found at [Ubuntu freeze on boot purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143309/ubuntu-freeze-on-boot-purple-screen) so that I might see what was happening when it hung, but the same screen results.  I also found [Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates) but it is referring to specific hardware types that I don't think apply to me (my Ubuntu 18.04 is running in VMWare Workstation Player 15).

Comment: can you try taking that VM image and booting it in virtualbox?

Comment: After a couple hours of conversion and importing, the VM boots OK, but in Virtual Box Ubuntu says there are no network adapters of any kind, so it is useless at the moment.  I have followed several step-by-step articles that I found here, but all assume the network device was found, but I don't know how to force ubuntu to discover the Virtual Box network manually.  It is set up as Bridged, and both Windows and my AV package have it enabled.  So, OS boots better, but without network is not usable, while in VMWare it boots only as recovery, but otherwise works perfectly.

Comment: hm I think you have to go into the configurations by right clicking on it in the list of VMs in virtualbox and then see if under "network", "access by bridge" is selected on "eno1"  with the checkboxes ticked. see if there's any config that's weird. "refuse promiscuous mode" is ok.

Comment: On VB's Network|Adapter 1 tab, Enable Network Adapter is checked, Attached to: Bridged Adapter, name: (my host's NIC).  In Advanced, Adapter Type is Intel PRO/1000, Promiscuios: Deny, MAC Addr 08002795F007, Cable Connected Checked, Fort Forwarding is grayed.  The other 3 adapter tabs are not enabled.  In Windows, both the VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Network Driver and the VMWare Bridge Protocol are checked for my hosts' NIC.  When booted, the Ubuntu 18.04 desktop configuration tool shows no option to configure a network except VPN (or wifi, which I don't have).

Comment: ok try switching it from bridge to NAT and leave the rest. actually you can even try adding more network interfaces at a time. this way you can test several settings with one boot. but I think NAT should do it.

Comment: Also, the kern.log for the last boot I tried shows that the Intel NIC was found.  10sec later, the VMware vmxnet3 virtual NIC driver logged its version, then an ip_tables copyright notice, then nothing else with 'net' in it.

Comment: Shutdown guest, switched VirtualBox to NAT, restarted guest.  No change.

Comment: darn. well I'm tapped out. could you test making a new ubuntu VM with virtualbox to see if the issue persists. in the meantime you can always set up shared folder on the VM that doesn't have internet to get files out of there.

Comment: Thanks for trying!  I'll stick with VMware because it works fine after I recover-to-boot.  FWIW, I activated all four adapters in VB as bridged, NAT, host-only and internal.  Ubuntu now sees 4 Intel NICs in the kern.log, but shows none in the network settings app.  It probably needs something from the internet in order to activate them!  Thanks again.

Comment: no problem! hope someone comes allong with a full solution!